# Regex to get a specific query string variable in a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a URL like

```
server/area/controller/action/4/?param=2"
```

in which the server can be

```
http://localhost/abc
https://test.abc.com
https://abc.om
```

I want to get the first character after **"action/"** which is 4 in the above URL, with a regex. Is it possible with regex in js, or is there any way?

Comment: I believe first parameter is `param=2` and not 4??

Comment: not actually this is mvc url so first parameter is 4.

Comment: i just want to get 4 from this string, let skip discussion about parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex `\d+(?=\/\?)`

```
var url = "server/area/controller/action/4/?param=2"; 
var param = url.match(/\d+(?=\/\?)/);
```

Test code [here](http://ideone.com/nwJNk).

Comment: If the first parameter may contain also non-digit characters, then use regex `[^\/]+(?=\/\?)`

Answer (score 1):

Using this regex in JavaScript:

```
action/(.)
```

Allows you to access the first matching group, which will contain the *first character* after `action/` -- see the examples at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTYH9/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This way splits the URL on the / characters and extracts the last but one element

```
var url = "server/area/controller/action/4/?param=2".split ('/').slice (-2,-1)[0];
```